# Display images from <content:encoded> on RSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, rss

I have a rss feed where I can actually display infos as title and decription. But I have no idea how to display image from there. Here is the original codepen https://codepen.io/jinzagon/pen/JjXNmLO , and bellow a simple example of an RSS I want to fetch the image from.

```
   <item>
            <title>Street Power Football &#8211; v1.0.12344.0</title>
            <link>https://fitgirl-repacks.site/street-power-football/</link>
                        <comments>https://fitgirl-repacks.site/street-power-football/#comments</comments>
            
            <dc:creator><![CDATA[FitGirl]]></dc:creator>
            <pubDate>Wed, 26 Aug 2020 23:18:33 +0000</pubDate>
                    <category><![CDATA[Lossless Repack]]></category>
            <guid isPermaLink="false">https://fitgirl-repacks.site/?p=15014</guid>
    
                        <description><![CDATA[<p>#1540 Street Power Football v1.0.12344.0 Genres/Tags: Sports, Soccer, Third-person, 3D Companies: SFL Interactive, Maximum Games Languages: RUS/ENG/MULTI12 Original Size: 4.1 GB Repack Size: 1.9 GB Download Mirrors Temporary hidden. Devs implemented a new server-sided check AFTER that cracked version was released. So all existing copies will continue to work, but new users can&#8217;t run it &#8230; <a href="https://fitgirl-repacks.site/street-power-football/" class="more-link">Continue reading <span class="screen-reader-text">Street Power Football &#8211; v1.0.12344.0</span> <span class="meta-nav">&#8594;</span></a></p>
    <p>The post <a rel="nofollow" href="https://fitgirl-repacks.site/street-power-football/">Street Power Football &#8211; v1.0.12344.0</a> appeared first on <a rel="nofollow" href="https://fitgirl-repacks.site">FitGirl Repacks</a>.</p>
    ]]></description>
                                            <content:encoded><![CDATA[<h3><span style="color: #339966;">#1540</span> <strong>Street Power Football <span style="color: #808080;">v1.0.12344.0</span></strong></h3>
    <p style="height: 200px; display: block;"><a target="_blank" href="http://en.riotpixels.com/games/street-power-football/" rel="noopener"><img class="alignleft" width="150" src="https://i112.fastpic.ru/big/2020/0827/f0/55df02beb4bfc89bf021aae2b85686f0.jpg" /></a><br />
    Genres/Tags: <strong>Sports, Soccer, Third-person, 3D</strong><br />
    Companies: <strong>SFL Interactive, Maximum Games</strong><br />
    Languages: <strong>RUS/ENG/MULTI12</strong><br />
    Original Size: <strong>4.1 GB</strong><br />
    Repack Size: <strong>1.9 GB</strong></p>
</item>
```

JS that shows the feed

```
const RSS_URL = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://fitgirl-repacks.site/feed/`;

fetch(RSS_URL)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(str => new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    const items = data.querySelectorAll("item");
    let html = ``;
    items.forEach(el => {
      html += `
        <article>
          <img src="${el.querySelector("link").innerHTML}/image/large.png" alt="">
          <h2>
            <a  href="${el.querySelector("link").innerHTML}" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
              ${el.querySelector("title").innerHTML}
 
            </a>
<h2>${el.querySelector("description").innerHTML}</h2>
          </h2>
        </article>
      `;
    });
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
  });
```

Comment: If all you want is the image src you will need to insert the html from <content:encoded> into a temporary element then query for that `<img>` element and get it's `src`

Comment: @charlietfl You mean like this ?  `${el.querySelector("<content:encoded>; img").innerHTML}` ?

Comment: No it's more complicated than that.... first you need the data in `<content:encoded>`. Then you need a temporary element to put that in as innerHTML. then you need to query inside that temporary element to get the img

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry I didn't understand. Can you please show me in code ?

Comment: `let div = document.createElement('div'); div.innerHTML = 'content from xml'; let img = div.querySelector('img').src`

Comment: @charlietfl I have the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null `. Can you please directly modify the codepen as you know what to modify ?